# Xamarin Forms binding - intercepting a bound value and changing it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a simple composed custom control that displays text set to a bound `ControlText` property.  In the example below, you can see when the button is clicked the control is updated.

[image]

How can I change the code so that the label shown by the control takes whatever is sent to it and converts it to all uppercase?

So instead of showing...

Count=5

it would show...

COUNT=5

*In this simple example an **IValueConverter** can be leveraged to accomplish this, but I want to see a different implementation for a much more complex example I need to implement.*  I am seeking a solution that intercepts the value being set in the code behind, converts it, and sets it to the ControlText property of the custom control.

**SimpleControl.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SimpleControl : ContentView
{
    public SimpleControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ControlTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                           propertyName: nameof(ControlText),
                                           returnType: typeof(string),
                                           declaringType: typeof(SimpleControl),
                                           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                           defaultValue: "Hello World");

    public string ControlText
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(ControlTextProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ControlTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Also, I would expect at runtime this breakpoint to be hit, but the code never stops on it.  I am setting the property from the SimplePageModel, so I find it strange this is never hit.  Can someone explain that to me as well?

[image]

**SimpleControl.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App7.SimpleControl"
             x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="100">
            <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=ControlText}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**SimplePage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App7"
             x:Class="App7.SimplePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:SimpleControl ControlText="{Binding ControlText}" />

            <Button Text="Update Control"
                Command="{Binding UpdateControl}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**SimplePageModel.cs (leveraging FreshMVVM)**

```
public class SimplePageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public SimplePageModel() { }

    private int _index;

    public string ControlText { get; set; }

    public Command UpdateControl
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((t) =>
            {
                ControlText = $"Count = {++_index}";
            });
        }
    }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        ControlText = $"Count = 0";

        base.Init(initData);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to see a different implementation for a much more complex example" - I'm not clear on why a value converter wouldn't suffice for even a more complex example?  Do you want to modify the stored value and not just the displayed value?

Comment: Yes, correct.  My real world control uses a BindableLayout to create a list of "tabs".  I want to bind a List<string> to a property in the control, but when it is set, I want to convert that to a List<Tab>.  I don't want to expose List<Tab> to the outside world, and just want the control to deal with that.  I was thinking if I can see how to do it with this simple example, then I will know how to do it for a more complex example.  Hope that helps a bit...

Comment: why not just do it in the setter?

Comment: I actually tried creating a _ControlText property the user control binds to.  And in the ControlText setter I converted the 'value' to uppercase and set _ControlText.  But it didn't work. In fact the breakpoint I show above never gets hit.  I am not sure why the breakpoint doesn't work either, but I can only assume the 'set' is never actually invoked.  Very confusing.

Comment: I think you'd be better off focusing on solving that problem than trying to come up with some complex workaround.  I saw your prior post but there is too much going on to be able to easily debug based on just what you posted.  If you want to share the code I wouldn't mind taking a quick look at it.

Comment: Hey John, we want to help. Could you please try to break down the problem better?

Comment: Thanks.  I am working on a simple codebase I can share so the problem can be seen better.

Comment: I posted a code sample at github.com/JohnLivermore/XamarinFormsControlDemo that shows how to resolve the issue.  I have it working now.  Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use triggers for this purpose, since its not too clear what is the idea in the background, I am just suggesting that it can be helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to the question : change the definition of your property from

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty ControlTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                           propertyName: nameof(ControlText),
                                           returnType: typeof(string),
                                           declaringType: typeof(SimpleControl),
                                           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                           defaultValue: "Hello World");
```

to

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty ControlTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                           propertyName: nameof(ControlText),
                                           returnType: typeof(string),
                                           declaringType: typeof(SimpleControl),
                                           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                           defaultValue: "Hello World", 
coerceValue: (bindable, value) =>
            {
                if (value!=null)
                    return ((string) value).ToUpper();
                return value;
            });
```